# Use of ternary operator inside filter and map method in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an `cart` object. I want to change the `qty` of a product in cart for which i have created a `changeQty` method inside which I am using `filter` method to find the respective product and then I am updating the `qty`.

If I pass other than 0 it works properly. But if I pass `0` as quantity to the `changeQty` method the product get's removed from the cart.

According to my knowledge `filter` works based on the return value. But here I am assigning `qty` to `product.qty`. And also If I use `map` instead of `filter` I am geting 0 in place of that product. So my doubt is what does `product.qty = qty` returns ?

```js
let cart = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Product 1",
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Product 2",
    qty: 1
  },
]

const changeQty = (pid, qty) => {
  cart = cart.filter(product => product.id === pid ? product.qty = qty : product)
  console.log(cart);
}

changeQty(1, 0)
```

Comment: `0 === (foo.bar = 0)` so your return value is `0` which is falsy so those values are filtered out.

Comment: You are trying to do too many things in your `filter` callback. Array.prototype.filter expects a truthy (keep) or falsy (throw out) value from the callback. The `product` object evaluates to true, where as the assignment on the right side returns `undefined` which evaluates to `false`, so the assignment will filter that entry out.

Here is some documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: *" I am using filter method to find the respective product and then I am updating the qty."*: it is almost the opposite: you are updating a product and then apply a filter.

Comment: If you want to find out what `product.qty = 0` returns, why not just try it in the console and log out the result?

Answer (score 2):

Use `map` instead of `filter`. You can use spread syntax and overwrite the value of `qty` for the product that matches the `id`.

```js
let cart = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Product 1",
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Product 2",
    qty: 1
  },
]

const changeQty = (pid, qty) => {
  cart = cart.map(product => product.id === pid ? { ...product, qty } : product)
  console.log(cart);
}

changeQty(1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

> if I pass 0 as quantity to the changeQty method the product get's removed from the cart.

That's because the assignment of 0 to `product.qty` evaluates to a 0 return value for the `filter` callback. That is a falsy value, indicating the current cart item should be filtered out. In fact, you don't want to filter at all. On the contrary, you don't want to change the length of the `cart` array.

If your goal is to mutate the cart structure, then possibly you are looking for `find` instead of `filter`:

```js
const cart = [{id:1,title:"Product 1",qty:1},{id:2,title:"Product 2",qty:1}];

const changeQty = (pid, qty) => {
  Object(cart.find(({id}) => id === pid)).qty = qty;
  console.log(cart);
}

changeQty(1, 0);
```

NB: the call to `Object` is to deal silently with a product that is not in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

You are modifying the source object which is very bad:

```js
let cart = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Product 1",
    qty: 1
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Product 2",
    qty: 1
  },
]

const changeQty = (pid, qty) => {
  cart.forEach(product => product.id === pid ? product.qty = qty : product)
  console.log(cart);
}

changeQty(1, 0)
```

That's why you are getting unexpected results

Comment: I don't think that's the reason this is happening.  It's because the filter predicate returns `0` when executing `product.qty = 0`.  Since this value is falsy, the product element in question is dropped from the filtered results.  Whether or not the source array should be modified is a fair question, but not the reason this fails.

Comment: "modifying the source object which is very bad". It is not "bad". It is just not what OP wants.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko true, getting cancer isn't bad, it's just not what most people want

Comment: @KonradLinkowski Well, I also don't like OOP but comparing it to cancer is a little bit too far...

Comment: I'm not against oop. Changing source array in `forEach` is fine, but not in `filter` as it is misleading

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do it with this one-liner:

```js
let cart = [{id: 1,title: "Product 1",qty: 1},{id: 2,title: "Product 2",qty: 1}];

const changeQty = (pid, qty) =>( cart.forEach(p => p.id===pid && (p.qty=qty)), cart );

console.log(changeQty(1, 0));
```

As OP's intention was to *change the input array* `cart` the `.forEach()` methods presents itself as a suitable candidate.

I don't know *how many cart items* there might be with your `p.id===pid`. In my snippet they would *all* be changed by getting an updated `qty` property. Trincot provides an `array.find()` based solution that is probably more performant but will only affect *the first* cart item matching the specified `pid`.